# Cannot use delegatecalls in Remix since either the addresses aren't displayed correcly or I cannot access the memory address?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation

For instance delegatecall to the same address works:

```
  function callTheOtherContract() public {
        require(address(this).delegatecall(bytes4(keccak256("callMe()"))));


    }

    event CallMe(address _from);

    function callMe() payable public {
        CallMeMaybeEvent(this);
        balances[0xD3755576a0413ADd8Ba11B5430692630DEa74cCE] += 1;
    }
```

However trying do call external addressed of a deployed remix contract "in memory" doesn't work:

```
  function call() public {
        address x =0xCab77B4B9BF9b92a53572091C5798C570051BE8f;
    x.delegatecall(bytes4(keccak256("tobecalled()"))); 
  }
```

Comment: in short: either I misstype the address of the external contract somehow or remix simply cannot access a "Deployed" contract in memory. Whenever I deploy something ofchain I simply click 'deploy' pink button to deploy to some random local address.

Comment: I tried and it does work. What does `tobecalled()` do? Do you known that delegatecall requires callee and caller to have a compatible storage layout?

Comment: Sorry I got it now...it was my misunderstanding of how delegatecall works, apparently you can't change the variables of contract A only of the contract that has delegatecall in its source.